# Google API project gone

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I'm using several Google API for a professional project for 6 years now (Maps, Places, Firebase, etc).

All of a sudden, the project stopped working yesterday evening. When I tried to figure it out on the Google Developers Console, the project is gone, pure and simple.

There is no trace whatsoever on the dashboard and all my credentials are missing!

I never got any prior notice from Google, and since you need a valid project to contact support, I'm 100% stuck...

Does this already happen to someone here?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple google accounts and just forgot to switch? Is this your project or project owned by someone else who previously granted you access?

Comment: @rkosegi This is my project and my only Google account...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related OP should contact google support directly.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for updating the tags. I think this question should stay open, since it could help other people who encounters the same issue.

Comment: you may want to consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic